# Recent Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 update causing crash?

Tags: server

My Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 was stable before I did an apt upgrade two days ago. The crash is random and there is no logging in the journalctl. When the system crashes the screen is blank and ssh does not respond. I have not made any changes to the hardware.

The following were updated, are there any known issues with the updates below?

```
Install: python3-magic:amd64 (2:0.4.24-2, automatic)
Upgrade: containerd.io:amd64 (1.6.8-1, 1.6.9-1), docker-compose-plugin:amd64 (2.12.0~ubuntu-jammy, 2.12.2~ubuntu-jammy), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:
20.10.20~3-0~ubuntu-jammy, 5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy), dbus-user-session:amd64 (1.12.20-2ubuntu4, 1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1), sosreport:amd64 (4.3-1u
buntu2.1, 4.4-1ubuntu1.22.04.1), tzdata:amd64 (2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0, 2022e-0ubuntu0.22.04.0), cockpit-system:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22.04.
1), cockpit-networkmanager:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.1), cockpit-bridge:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ub
untu0.22.04.1), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.12.20-2ubuntu4, 1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1), docker-ce:amd64 (5:20.10.20~3-0~ubuntu-jammy, 5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-ja
mmy), cockpit:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), cockpit-ws:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), docker-ce-rootless-extras:amd64 (5:20.10.20~3
-0~ubuntu-jammy, 5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy), snapd:amd64 (2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1, 2.57.5+22.04), cockpit-packagekit:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22
.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.5, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.6), docker-scan-plugin:amd64 (0.17.0~ubuntu-jammy, 
0.21.0~ubuntu-jammy), cockpit-storaged:amd64 (264-1, 264-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.1), dbus:amd64 (1.12.2
0-2ubuntu4, 1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1), fwupd:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.1)
```

Comment: There is no mention of docker in the question. There is mention of docker in the update message. Please edit the question and add the missing possibly critical details.